# Getting reference from one bean to another dynamically

Tags: cdi, javabeans, quarkus

Is it possible to get a reference from one `@ApplicationScoped` bean to another by dynamic way, some like JNDI lookup, or `getBeanByName`?

For example:

```js
@ApplicationScoped
public class MaltiService {
    @Inject
    BeanManager mgr;

    public JsonObject execute(JsonObject request, String taskClassName) {
  
      // for eaxample taskClassName="com.mybean.MyTask"
      // Does not work ...
      Set<Bean<?> beans = mgr.getBeans(taskClassName);
      .....
      myTasksInterface.performTask();
      
  }
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class MyTask implements MyTasksInterface {

  public performTask() {
    // Do something ....
  }
}
```

Could somebody clarify, how to get bean reference by name or class or some another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

The idea is to select Service Bean according to service name in the JSON request or according to some external configuration.
@Unremovable annotation prevents removing bean by Quarkus in case then it is not injected directly.

```js
@ApplicationScoped
public class MaltiService {
    @Inject
    BeanManager mgr;

    public JsonObject execute(JsonObject request, String taskClassName) {
      MyTasksInterface myTasksInterface = getServiceBean(request.get("taskClassName"));
      // do somthing
      return myTasksInterface.performTask(JsonObject request);
      
    }

    //Method example to get a bean reference
    private MyTasksInterface getServiceBean(String beanClassName) throws Exception {
     ServiceJsonTask ret = null;
     Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(beanClassName);
     Set<Bean<?>> beans = mgr.getBeans(clazz);
     if (beans != null && beans.iterator().hasNext()) {
         Bean<?> bean = beans.iterator().next();
         CreationalContext<?> ctx = mgr.createCreationalContext(bean);
         ret = (ServiceJsonTask) mgr.getReference(bean, clazz, ctx);
     }
     return ret;
     }
}

// Annotate bean as @Unremovable
@ApplicationScoped
@Unremovable
public class MyTask implements MyTasksInterface {

  public JsonObject performTask(JsonObject request) {
    JsonObject ret = new JsonObject();
    // Do something ....
    return ret;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add some text and context to the code, what you had to change and why

Comment: I think you can also do just `CDI.current().select(Class)`, if you have a `Class` object. The `@Unremovable` part is crucial, though, as you've already found.

Comment: Yes, CDI.current().select(Class) works with @Unremovable also.